# Python Instagram API, count() takes exactly one argument

Tags: python, api, instagram

I am trying to get the likes of the current instagram photo, all the other API calls work and return valid things. but when I get to  media.likes.count I get:

TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

```
tags = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name='tag',max_id=max_id_next)
for media in tags[0]:
    url = media.images['standard_resolution'].url
    max_id_next = tags[1].split("max_tag_id=")[1]
    pic_user = media.user.username
    pic_id = media.id
    pic_link = media.link.split("p/")[1].replace('/','')
    profile_pic = media.user.profile_picture
    likes = media.likes.count
    print likes
```

Any Idea? It says I should be supplying it with an argument, but I wouldn't know what argument to give it, I am expecting it to return me total number of likes for the current element.

Using: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

Endpoint: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

```
"likes": {
        "count": 1,
        "data": [{
            "username": "mikeyk",
            "full_name": "Mike Krieger",
            "id": "4",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg"
        }]
    },
```

Answer (score 5):

From reading the [source](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/models.py#L51) it seems you should use `media.like_count` instead.

Comment: Don't think that works, as it just counts the initially returned stuff in that list (you can load more through pagination).

There is a returned JSON field for count, I am just trying to grab it.

Comment: How about switching `media.likes.count` to `media.like_count`? If that fixed the problem I'll amend my answer.

Comment: That did fix the problem! Thank you! Amend your answer and I'll mark it as correct! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I saved the amended answer.